# Need help identifying this drywall anchor used to lock in a ceiling air diffuser

Tags: hvac, drywall, drywall-anchor

Just finishing a whole house paining job and had to pull down all ceiling registers.  A few of the drywall locks went missing and I need to buy more but have no idea what they are called and cannot find them online.  This is what they look like:
[image]

I am sure they are on Amazon but have run out of search ideas.  Thanks for the help IDing it!!

Comment: Please show how that part mates with the ceiling register. This will help with someone being able to possibly recommend some alternative. This part may very well be manufacturer specific and finding generic replacements in the marketplace would be unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed quite a few registers like that but have never found them for sale. I have made them out of scraps of polypropylene, and UHMW. Most had to be shaped on 1 side a belt sander worked well for that holding the plastic with pliers. A few I could put in without shaping but not very many.  Note if you drill the hole with a drill it needs to be smaller than the screw size the screw needs to bite into the plastic and rotate out when tightened.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if these come with new registers?  They are cheap enough.  Guess I can always buy 4 new ones and solve the problem that way.

Comment: Many retrofit registers do have them But not all. many times we will fold a piece of scrap duct work on both sides of the Sheetrock or wallboard and shoot a self piercing through that (self tapping cut a bigger hole in the metal and don’t hold well on sheet metal so we use self piercing more often). The metal tabs 3 on a round register hold quite well.

Answer (score 0):

"Old work" electrical boxes have similar tabs.  I've never seen tabs like that sold separately, but the electric boxes are cheap enough that you could just buy a few for the screws and tabs they come with.  Note the tab sticking up in the picture.

[image]